# difference yap and swi-prolog reading canonical lists

Tags: file, prolog, swi-prolog, yap

I have the following test code trying to read file into a list

```
open('raw250-split1.pl', read, Stream),
read(Stream,train_xs(TrainXs)),
length(TrainXs, MaxTrain).
```

I will omit part of the output due to the file is quite large.

It works well with `yap`,

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ yap                                                      [18/06/19| 5:48PM]
% Restoring file /usr/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Sep 17 13:59:03 UTC 2016
   ?- open('raw250-split1.pl', read, Stream),                                                           
      read(Stream, train_xs(TrainXs)),                                                                     
      length(TrainXs, MaxTrain).
MaxTrain = 225,
Stream = '$stream'(3),
TrainXs = [[parse([which,rivers,run,through,states,bordering,new,mexico,/],answer(_A,(river(_A),traverse(_A,_B),next_to(_B,_C),const(_C,stateid('new mexico')))))],
<omited output>
,[parse([what,is,the,largest,state,capital,in,population,?],answer(_ST,largest(_SU,(capital(_ST),population(_ST,_SU)))))]]
```

But on `swi-prolog`, it will produce `Type error`

```
➜  chill git:(master) ✗ swipl                                                     [18/06/19| 7:24PM]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- open('raw250-split1.pl', read, Stream),    
   read(Stream, train_xs(TrainXs)),                                                                     
   length(TrainXs, MaxTrain).
ERROR: raw250-split1.pl:4:
    Type error: `list' expected, found `parse(which.(rivers.(run.(through.(states.(bordering.(new.(mexico.((/).[])))))))),
    <omited output>
,answer(_67604,(state(_67604),next_to(_67604,_67628),const(_67628,stateid(kentucky))))).[].(parse(what.((is).(the.(largest.(state.(capital.(in.(population.((?).[])))))))),answer(_67714,largest(_67720,(capital(_67714),population(_67714,_67720))))).[].[]))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))' (a compound)
    In:
      [10] throw(error(type_error(list,...),context(...,_67800)))
       [7] <user>

    Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
    Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

What might be the problem for the error here?

File `raw250-split1.pl` can be found from the `ftp` url below, if you'd like to try it.

Thank you for the help!

---

*I am trying to migrate an earlier code to `SWI-Prolog`, which was written in
`SICStus 3 #3: Thu Sep 12 09:54:27 CDT 1996` or earlier
by Raymond J. Mooney ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/mooney/chill/. 
All the questions with this tag are all related to this task. I'm new to prolog, helps and suggestions are welcomed!*

Comment: Consider to use SICStus 4: It has an incredibly fast JIT-compiler

Comment: @false Thanks! Our school doesn't have the license. I installed one for evaluation. Just have to reapply for another one when it expires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `raw250-split1.pl` was apparently written using canonical notation. The traditional list functor is `./2` but SWI-Prolog 7.x changed it to `'[|]'/2` in order to use `./2` for other purposes. This results in the the variable `TrainXs` being instantiated by the `read/2` call to a compound term whose argument **is not** a list:

```
?- open('raw250-split1.pl', read, Stream), read(Stream,train_xs(TrainXs)).
Stream = <stream>(0x7f8975e08e90),
TrainXs = parse(which.(rivers.(run.(through.(states.(bordering.(... . ...)))))), answer(_94,  (river(_94), traverse(_94, _100), next_to(_100, _106), const(_106, stateid('new mexico'))))).[].(parse(what.((is).(the.(highest.(point.(... . ...))))), answer(_206,  (high_point(_204, _206), const(_204, stateid(montana))))).[].(parse(what.((is).(the.(most.(... . ...)))), answer(_298, largest(_300,  (population(_298, _300), state(...), ..., ...)))).[].(parse(through.(which.(states.(... . ...))), answer(_414,  (state(_414), const(..., ...), traverse(..., ...)))).[].(parse(what.((is).(... . ...)), answer(_500, longest(_500, river(...)))).[].(parse(how.(... . ...), answer(_566,  (..., ...))).[].(parse(... . ..., answer(..., ...)).[].(parse(..., ...).[].(... . ... .(... . ...))))))))).
```

YAP still uses the `./2` functor for lists, which explains why it can handle it. A workaround for SWI-Prolog is to start it with the `--traditional` command-line option:

```
$ swipl --traditional
...
?- open('raw250-split1.pl', read, Stream), read(Stream,train_xs(TrainXs)).
Stream = <stream>(0x7faeb2f77700),
TrainXs = [[parse([which, rivers, run, through, states, bordering|...], answer(_94,  (river(_94), traverse(_94, _100), next_to(_100, _106), const(_106, stateid('new mexico')))))], [parse([what, is, the, highest, point|...], answer(_206,  (high_point(_204, _206), const(_204, stateid(montana)))))], [parse([what, is, the, most|...], answer(_298, largest(_300,  (population(_298, _300), state(...), ..., ...))))], [parse([through, which, states|...], answer(_414,  (state(_414), const(..., ...), traverse(..., ...))))], [parse([what, is|...], answer(_500, longest(_500, river(...))))], [parse([how|...], answer(_566,  (..., ...)))], [parse([...|...], answer(..., ...))], [parse(..., ...)], [...]|...].
```

The type error you get is due to the `length/2` expecting a list when the first argument is bound.

Comment: The current version of SWI can parse and highlight that source without problems. Now I'll try read/2 as well.

Comment: Thank both of you! It seems compatibility is a real challenge when learning `prolog`.

Comment: I can confirm read/2 works as well, and the problem is indeed the tilde at EOF

Comment: The migration to `yap` can run but with error now, it seems more work to be done on `swi-prolog`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CapelliC On my machine, adding `--traditional` can also work with that tilde.

Comment: Oops. Pardon for the noise, I didn't understood well the question. Indeed, it's related to what you explained.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tilde as last character in that file, causing the syntax being invalid, so you should remove it before reading. I don't know why YAP accept the file as valid, should raise an error AFAIK.

Comment: I tried to remove that tilde, but the error persists.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that, but it's most probably irrelevant. Are you sure you removed the tilde from the file actually read ?

Comment: I double checked that with `tail`, `))))))))).`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a read option dotlists/2 in SWI-Prolog:

> **dotlists(Bool)**
>       If true (default false), read .(a,[]) as a 
>       list, even if lists are internally nor constructed 
>       using the dot as functor. This is primarily intended 
>       to read the output from write_canonical/1 from 
>       other Prolog systems. See section 5.1.
>   http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_term/2

This gives you the desired result, without changing the mode:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.0)

?- read_term(X, [dotlists(true)]).
|: .(a,.(b,.(c,[]))).
X = [a, b, c].
```